# Nodejs busboy is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, busboy

I just containerised a nodejs based serverside app  and getting this error below any assistance will be greatly appreciated. i had this same app running on ec2 instance without any issue at all

```
0|src | GET /.env 404 1.499 ms - 43
10|src | 2022-03-23T18:05:11.118Z - error: \*\* Error: Status: 500 Message: Busboy is not a constructor
10|src | POST / 500 2.442 ms - 27
11|src | GET /ping 200 1.145 ms - 18
13|src | GET /ping 200 2.026 ms - 18
12|src | GET /ping 200 1.166 ms - 18
15|src | GET /ping 200 1.128 ms - 18
14|src | 2022-03-23T18:05:55.508Z - error: \*\* Error: Status: 500 Message: Busboy is not a constructor
14|src | POST /lessons?downloadLanguage=en&localize=false&allowMT=false 500 1.425 ms - 27
9|src  | GET /ping 200 1.154 ms - 18
8|src  | GET /ping 200 1.128 ms - 18
```

any time i want to upload a file i get this error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the docker node image version from v10 to v14 and connect-busboy version from v0.0.2 to v1.0.0.0 and it take care of the busboy is not a constructor error for me